# Python Regex -Parse a string and split it by comma & dollar

Tags: regex, python-3.x, spacy

I have a sentence like this-

```
stmt ="Is abc service accessible to sd, rc & odd in XYZ?"
```

And I have entities in string like this -

```
str_entities= "abc service$Service,sd,rc & odd$Processes, XYZ$Name"
```

I want to convert these entities in the spacy json format eg. which contains the word indexes for each entity and the label for that entity

```
(stmt, {"entities": [(3,14, 'Service'),(30, 41, 'Processes'), (46, 48, 'Name')]})
```

I tried below regex but it works for only one case, i want a generic one which can extract any no. of entities.

```
re.findall("(.*.?)\$(\S+),(.*.?)\$(\S+)", str_entities)
```

I hv 10000s of such rows in many files, want to generate that format so that i can train a custom spacy model. I am not able to generate entities as the commas are splitting the entities multiple times and I am loosing the word to find the indexes from the stmt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understood you correctly, but I would split the **str_entities** with

```
[^ ^,]+[^\$]*\$[^\$^,]+
```

so that you get both, the string and the entity still combined with the $ sign. After that you can go through the elements with a for statement and get the index values.

```
enentity_list=[]
for e in re.findall("[^ ^,]+[^\$]*\$[^\$^,]+", str_entities):
    entity_list.append((stmt.index(e.split('$')[0]),stmt.index(e.split('$')[0])+len(e.split('$')[0]),e.split('$')[1]))
json=(stmt,{"entities":entity_list})
```

You can try it on https://rextester.com/LRKTPL77140